# Next.JS useRouter will only returns an empty object for a dynamic route

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am making a bit of a specialized calendar application in Next.JS and I am have some problems with dynamic routing that I can't seem to figure out.
I have two similar pages with similar routes, where one is working perfectly fine and the other not working at all.

First page (working):

```
// pages/date/[year]/[month]/[dayOfMonth].tsx
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { Day } from "../../../../components/Day";

type StringQueryParams = Record<keyof QueryParams, string>;

interface QueryParams {
  year: number;
  month: number;
  dayOfMonth: number;
}

const transformParams = ({ year, month, dayOfMonth }: StringQueryParams): QueryParams => ({
  year: parseInt(year),
  month: parseInt(month),
  dayOfMonth: parseInt(dayOfMonth),
});

const DayPage: React.FC = () => {
  const { query } = useRouter();
  const params = transformParams(query as StringQueryParams);
  return <Day {...params} />;
};

export default DayPage;
```

Second page (not working)

```
// pages/date/[year]/[month].tsx
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { Month } from "../../../components/Month";
import { validateMonth } from "../../../lib/month";

type StringQueryParams = Record<keyof QueryParams, string>;

interface QueryParams {
  month: string;
  year: number;
}

const MonthDisplay: React.FC = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  debugger;
  const { query } = router;
  const { month: rawMonth, year: rawYear } = query as StringQueryParams;
  console.log("query:", query);
  console.log("router:", router);
  const month = validateMonth(rawMonth);
  const year = parseInt(rawYear);

  return <Month name={month} year={year} />;
};

export default MonthDisplay;
```

With output

```
query: {}
router: ServerRouter {
  route: '/date/[year]/[month]',
  pathname: '/date/[year]/[month]',
  query: {},
  asPath: '/date/[year]/[month]',
  basePath: '',
  events: undefined,
  isFallback: false
}
```

I cannot for the life of me seem to figure out why the dynamic routing for the second page is not working at all, and not returning any query from the `useRouter()` hook.

Comment: can u explain what is not not working and what route does it take to when visit second page?

Comment: and in what component are u using these two component

Comment: can you make a reproduction repo in codesandbox or github

Answer (score 4):

Moving `pages/date/[year]/[month].tsx` to `pages/date/[year]/[month]/index.tsx` should work

Answer (score 1):

Your tree should be look like this

```
Pages
  [years]
    [months]
      index.tsx --> your 2nd page
      [days]
        indes.tsx --> your first page
```

[image]

[Documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes)